# Encrypting uploaded files in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a working file upload system, but i need to encrypt the uploaded file without saving the real file on the server.

I've tried to just use the `security->encryptByKey()` function, but this returns a string - and the `saveAs()`function is not available on strings. (The upload function works without the 4th line in the following code).

```
public function upload()
{
    $filename = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    $this->file = Yii::$app->security->encryptByKey($this->docFile, Yii::$app->security->generateRandomKey());
    if ($this->file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@frontend').'/uploads/encrypted/' . $filename . '.' . $this->file->extension)) {
        return $filename . '.' . $this->file->extension;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
public function upload(UploadedFile $file, $key)
{
    $filename = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    $filePath = Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/uploads/encrypted/' . $filename . '.' . $file->extension;
    $encryptedContent = Yii::$app->security->encryptByKey(file_get_contents($file->tempName), $key);
    if (file_put_contents($filePath, $encryptedContent)) {
        return $filename . '.' . $file->extension;
    }

    return false;
}
```

[`UploadedFile`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile) is only simple helper which simplify copying or moving uploaded files, but it does not hold file content (which makes sense - file could have few GB). To get real content you need to read it from disk by [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and save by [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). Note that whole concept may be really bad idea for big files - it may work slow and you will get memory exceeding problems.

Comment: Thank you. The file size will not be a problem. Btw, the `encryptByKey()' function is missing a second argument in your answer.